# How to find all classes under table tag in python using web scraping library beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
req = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_University")
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup.table["class"]
```

Comment: hi, what is your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Add this and you will find the class of table in that page.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
soup.table["class"]

Result:
['infobox', 'vcard']
```